# Opentsdb downsample not workding

Tags: opentsdb

I have used opentsdb http api like below

http://192.168.1.249:4242/api/query?start=10m-ago&m=sum:rate:swagent.network.send&downsample=interval:10m-avg

It is not working for me.

How to use downsample to reduce opentsdb response?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the downsampling function after the aggregator, like,

```
m=sum:5d-avg:cpu.load.serv1{tag=value}
```

where `5d-avg` is the downsampling function.